# How to use CTRubyAnnotationRef in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here is sample objective-c code from http://nshipster.com/ios8/

```
@import CoreText;
NSString *kanji = @"猫";
NSString *hiragana = @"ねこ";
CFStringRef furigana[kCTRubyPositionCount] =
    {(__bridge CFStringRef)hiragana, NULL, NULL, NULL};
CTRubyAnnotationRef ruby =
    CTRubyAnnotationCreate(kCTRubyAlignmentAuto, kCTRubyOverhangAuto, 0.5, furigana);
```

I am a new iOS programmer learning Swift. I am seeing that it would be good to know some objective-c so as to translate some code samples to Swift.

I am trying to translate the above code. Here is what I have so far:

```
import CoreText
import Foundation

var kanji: NSString = "猫"
var hiragana: NSString = "ねこ"
```

In my playground these first lines aren't getting any errors, but the rest is 'all messed up'. That is as far as I can get without doing some objective-c tutorials.

Can someone please help me finish this out?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I think you would do it in Swift 3.

```
let kanji = "猫"
var hiragana = "ねこ" as CFString
var furigana: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef> = UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef>.allocate(capacity: 4)
defer {
  furigana.deallocate(capacity: 4) // don't forget to clean up 
}
furigana.initialize(to: kCFNull, count: 4)
furigana[0] = hiragana as CFTypeRef

var ruby: CTRubyAnnotation!
furigana.withMemoryRebound(to: Unmanaged<CFString>.self, capacity: 4) { ptr in
  ruby = CTRubyAnnotationCreate(CTRubyAlignment.auto, CTRubyOverhang.auto, 0.5, ptr)
}
```

In Swift 4:

```
var ruby: CTRubyAnnotation!
furigana.withMemoryRebound(to: Optional<Unmanaged<CFString>>.self, capacity: 4) { ptr in
  ruby = CTRubyAnnotationCreate(CTRubyAlignment.auto, 
                                CTRubyOverhang.auto, 0.5, ptr)
}
```

Comment: I've got this error message: Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>?>'

Comment: Also, how do you attach this ruby text to your kanji? I don't see the kanji variable being used after you intialised it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UnmanagedMutablePointer to "simulate" C arrays. And for the other parameters, check out the Swift API docs for `CTRubyAnnotationCreate`. That helped me a lot :)

```
import CoreText
import Foundation

var kanji: NSString = "猫"
var hiragana: NSString = "ねこ"
var null: Unmanaged<CFString>?

var furigana: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>?> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>?>.alloc(4)

furigana[0] = Unmanaged.passUnretained(hiragana)
furigana[1] = null
furigana[2] = null
furigana[3] = null

var ruby: Unmanaged<CTRubyAnnotation> = CTRubyAnnotationCreate(CTRubyAlignment.Auto, CTRubyOverhang.Auto, 0.5, furigana)
```

Comment: Is there a way to see the text and its annotation in the playground?

Comment: I dont think so, sorry

Answer (score 0):

this code worked in Swift4.2:

```
let hiragana = "ねこ" as CFString
let furigana: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef> = 
UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef>.allocate(capacity: 4)

furigana.initialize(repeating: ("" as CFString), count: 4)
furigana[0] = hiragana

var ruby: CTRubyAnnotation!
furigana.withMemoryRebound(to: Optional<Unmanaged<CFString>>.self, capacity: 4) { ptr in

    ruby = CTRubyAnnotationCreate(CTRubyAlignment.auto, CTRubyOverhang.auto, 0.5, ptr)
}
```